# How can I change a CSS file permanently so the changes are saved in the actual file on the server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a back-end admin section for a site i am building and I would like to allow the site owner to change the background image of a particular element on the public page.

Is the best/only way to go about this by renaming my style.css file to style.php and then use a php variable to fill in the URL of the background-image style. I could then update that variable from a database.

I know this has been asked before but most answers/articles online are from around 2009. Is this the accepted way to do this? Is there a better way to do this yet using javascript/jQuery or having a server side php script that is able to alter the actual CSS file sitting on the server instead of embedding the php in the style sheet.

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple backgrunds already uploaded, and the admin just needs to choose between them?

Comment: i would just go with rendering the css inside a <style> tag inside the html page using php. because its so must easier and less buggy.

Comment: @Gnuey i have a background img uploaded already but i want the admin to be able to upload a completely new img for the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the question in your title, you can certainly have a server-side script simply read the CSS file using a function like [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), make the modification, and then write it out again at the same path.

Is this a good idea? That depends on your preferences and your needs.

Comment: That would be my preference however I am using SaaS that only outputs one massive main.css file. Because of that would it be quite difficult to find that one style and change it through file_get_contents? I only have one style sheet for performance reasons, if I were to add a second style sheet that only has the background image style, would that be better performance wise then doing the same through a <style> tag in the head as astro mentioned?

Comment: @GifCo, Performance-wise, It would be better to use astro's suggestion than adding a second style sheet for just one background image style.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to edit the css file with php than to serve the file styles.php.

The reason is that a .css file will get cached, while the .php file wouldn't. Since the css file only changes rarely, it is better to cache it. You could configure a rather short cache lifetime for .css files.